# ASP.Net MVC Jquery Autocomplete - list not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented an autocomplete in my app for retrive a list of users, but the list is not displaying when I search a user.

In my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(function () {
           $('#txtListUsers').autocomplete({
               source: '@Url.Action("GetJsonUsers","GestioneLega")',
               minLength: 2
           });
       });
   })
</script>
...
<input type="text" id="txtListUsers" />
```

My Action:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonUsers(string term)
{
    var users = GestServices.GetUsersForAutocomplete(term);
    return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Get data:

```
public static object GetUsersForAutocomplete(string searchTerm)
{
    object users = null;

    using (var db = new FriendsContext())
    {
        users = from cust in db.Users.Where(c => c.UserName.StartsWith(searchTerm))
                        select cust.UserName;
    }
    return users;
}
```

**The function GetJsonUsers not works:** doing more tests, I noticed that in GetUsersForAutocomplete function, the variable "users" is filled only in the using scope. if I do an immediate control on users out of using scope, obtain:
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

I solved this problem by following this discussion [The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617698/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints on GetJsonUsers and trace through to an error. You can also see what is coming back to your browser using f12.

Comment: The function GetJsonUsers works. In my browser (with f12) I don't see new elements / tags

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
       $('#txtListUsers').autocomplete({
          source:function( request, response ) {
              $.ajax({
              url: "@Url.Action("YourActionName","YourControllerName")",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {},
              success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                       label: item.name,
                       value: item.name
                           }
                         }));
              }
             });
             },
           minLength: 2
       });
```

Comment: have u debugged and seen what is the data your receiving in success call of ajax?

Comment: I have updated my answer. watch for url now. and set brealpoint on action and whether its getting hit or not.

Comment: Yes, the action is call and return the object.

Comment: Ok then whats the problem now?

Comment: I tried to use firebug for dubug javascript code, "data" seems to be empty. I don't see the list of elements for autocomplete

Comment: Ok. Try Changing your datatype from `jsonp` to `json`

Comment: Have a look at my approved answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402951/asp-net-mvc4-jquery-autocomplete-not-working/18515744#18515744